# MYSQL create view that show data from two tables

Tags: mysql, view

I have 2 tables

```
deposits 
id  |userId | amount|   Date
1   |  2    |  150  |   2013-11-22 02:57:00
2   |  3    |  230  |   2013-11-25 03:19:00

withdrawals 
id  |userId | amount|   Date
1   |  2    |  150  |   2013-11-23 02:57:00
2   |  3    |  190  |   2013-11-27 02:27:00
```

I want to create a view that will show data from both tables in this format
Preferably the records should be ordered by the date field, though it is not critical since I can Query the view with order by date.

```
depositsAndWithdrawal
type        |   id  | userId| amount    |   Date
deposit     |   1   |  2    |     150   |   2013-11-22 02:57:00
withdrawal  |   1   |  2    |     150   |   2013-11-23 02:57:00
deposit     |   2   |  3    |     230   |   2013-11-25 03:19:00
withdrawal  |   2   |  3    |     190   |   2013-11-27 02:27:00
```

Is this even possible? or do I need to create a new table and use the on insert event to add a relevant line to that table?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `union all` query.  And you can do this in a MySQL view:

```
create view v as
    select  'deposit' as which, id, userId, amount, Date
    from deposits 
    union all
    select  'withdrawals' as which, id, userId, amount, Date
    from withdrawals ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following (excuse small errors):

```
create view depositsAndWithdrawal as
(
   select 'deposits' as type, id, userID, amount, date 
   from deposits 
   UNION
   select 'withdrawls' as type, id, userID, amount, date 
   from widthdrawls
)
```

You can then query this using:

```
select * from  depositsAndWithdrawal order by date;
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can have the view order this as you would need to use a temporary table within the view e.g.:

**Doesn't work:**

```
create view depositsAndWithdrawal as
    (
       select * from
       (select 'deposits' as type, id, userID, amount, date 
       from deposits 
       UNION
       select 'withdrawls' as type, id, userID, amount, date 
       from widthdrawls) as temp order by date
    )
```

But you could split the problem into two views:

```
create view depositsAndWithdrawalTemp as
    (
       select 'deposits' as type, id, userID, amount, date 
       from deposits 
       UNION
       select 'withdrawls' as type, id, userID, amount, date 
       from widthdrawls
    )

create view depositsAndWithdrawal as
select * from depositsAndWithdrawalTemp order by date;
```