# Create a mysql view that contains 1 field getting in two data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Table1**

```
id | filename | created
```

**Table2**

```
id | filename | created
```

(Note: filename consists of images names)

When i run the code below:

`'Column 'filename' in field list is ambiguous'`  appears

if i specified the the filename like 'p.filename'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vmedia AS

SELECT
   filename
FROM Table1 p1

LEFT JOIN Table2 p2
```

Question: is it possible to make a mysql view that consists of 1 field but it has the field data of two tables?

Comment: `SELECT p1.filename` or `SELECT p2.filename` depending on the purpose

Comment: sql does not know which filename you are referring since both table have column filename, you need to specifiy it, either p1.filename or p2.filename will do

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152293/mysql-create-view-that-show-data-from-two-tables) answered my question

```
create view vmedia as
select  'Table1Media' as which, id, filename, created
from Table1 
union all
select  'Table2Media' as which, id, filename, created
from Table2 
union all
select  'Table3Media' as which, id, filename, created
from Table3 ;
```